# Smart Cards basic security issues

Tags: security

I have some basic ambiguities related to Smart cards, so I hope someone can answer these questions:

Does Smart Cards have any key for encription or authentication purposes (not speaking of PIN), inserted in it during personalization phase ?
If it has, is it only one key for all purposes (authentication, encription)  or there are more of them (assuming single application card) ? 
In order for authentication (between card and terminal) to be fulfilled how terminal learns the cards encription key (I understood that for authentication to take place both parties should have the same key).
I red part 3 and 4 of ISO7816, but didn't find details regarding that matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: tale from my working experience since I didn't receive proper training course, my wording my seems weird

Let's say java card is tiny computer with a little bit of processing power and memory
it do have os (e.g. java card vm) installed on them

You do need to have correct key to install application (applet) on them (should come along with sdk from card manufacturer)

It may have some usable applet installed, mostly example like memory storage (you can put data, get data)
If anything like applet that will store secured data, you may need to write one yourself.
And that authentication is on application layer, of course it not mention in ISO7816-4.

---

> Does Smart Cards have any key ...

It is on OS level and you need one to tamper with applet inside (intstall/delete), more than that is on application level and may differ a lot by applet vendor

> ... how terminal learns the cards encription key ...

Either have symmetrical key hard-coded before hand (in terminal code and in applet code)
then once both come in contact for first time, do generate new key and replace it blah blah blah

Or you can put different generated key along with applet file when you install applet (at least Gemalto can)
then use pinpad or some other mean to input that key on terminal as well

Comment: I am sorry for not being familiar with Java cards, but the answer provides good directions. My questions are more related to using commands quoted in 7816-4 (GET CHALLENGE, ETERNAL AUTHENTICATION ...), which I red about only.

Comment: I see, we should wait for next answer :)   , quite interested too

Comment: The question arose from another simple one- if I buy some Smart Card and want to authenticate it (INTERNAL AUTHENTICATE command), then how do I know what key the card has (for authenticate purposes) and what algorithm it uses for encription (as part of challenge- response process).

Comment: I suppose that should come with sdk, no ? what tool you use now to communicate with card ? I'm afraid that you can't just construct bytes and send apdu to card in development phase

Comment: It is all about low level programming. I have ARM microcontroller on one side and card on the other side. For the beginning, I would like to have some kind of authentication (apart from PIN) and also the way to store data in some EF (in card file system), and retrieve it, when needed.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, I would like to emphasis that I intend to use card by accessing it directly (at it's pins), with no reader in between. Also, regarding your comment, I think I can send some string to card for authentication but the problem is how could I interpret card's response (which is SOMEHOW (?) encripted with SOME (?) key).

Comment: Of course you could, at the low level, using some com port library and construct bytes array for apdu and send that to smart card. Or maybe at at little more higher level, there's something like pyscard for python (I think RaspPI do support that but don't know about ARM)

Comment: That secret key for 0x88 should be provided along with sdk or from someone you bought smart card from

Comment: I agree and expect so from supplier as well as details of crypt algorithm for authentication so the card and ARM should do the same. What I don't expect are key per card, but rather one key as master for deriving keys for all the cards bought. I think that supplier also derives per-card keys from master (for card series) and cards serial number (algorithm= ?) which I should also do on ARM side. It would be impractical for ARM to know all the possible card keys. That is what I think, but does it stand in reality ?